# laravel 7 all routes directing to home on live server but routes work on local

Tags: php, laravel-7

Trouble routing in laravel 7 on live server. I have all my routes protected in the admin and in local, Every link works as expected. However, on my live server, every route leads to home. Even if I hover over the link, at the bottom I see the route referrenced correctly. For example https://examplesite.com/admin. When I click it, it directs me home. What I am not clear on is what I need to do differently to get me routes back.
Here is my Login Controller:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

All my admin routes in web.php are wrapped inside the following:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function () {
});
```

In my protected $routeMiddleware, I have:

```
 'isAdmin' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
```

My AdminMiddleware is as follows:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role_as == 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'You are not permitted to access the User dashboard.');
        }
    }
```

my routes are like: `href="{{ route('myroute') }}"`

Here is an example of some of my routes in the blade template:
[image: routes image example]
Any clues to watch out for when moving the site to the live server? Thank you.

Comment: Have you got a log for your production env ?

Comment: @Gary Houbre . Thank you for your comment. Where would I find this log. I have debugging on for the initial stage of this project.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies. I forgot to add role_as to my database and then add admin to the column. Not that it is added, all is working as expected.